# MS SQL pattern for like

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can i search in sql by this rules:

1. field should begins from no or one and more '0'
2. field should end some number, for example 555

In other words pattern should match next records:

```
'555'
'0555'
'00555'
etc
```

Can sql do this in one select query (without string splitting or something else)?
Thank you.

Comment: *1. field should begins from zero and more '0'* – `'555'` doesn't start with a zero.

Comment: sorry, I mean from no or one and more 0

Comment: @AlexeiMalashkevich do you mean "zero or more '0' characters"?

Comment: "zero or more" is a null condition - in other words, it'a always satisfied by default, so you can scrap (ignore) it.

Comment: I think you didn't express your condition clearly. What you are missing is: "and the field should not contain any other characters except the (zero or more) leading zeros and the ending '555' ". (Otherwise, strings like "1555" match the condition the way you have stated it).

Comment: @HelenCraigman two rules above cover all cases. Your case "1555" covers first rule **field should begins from no or one and more '0'**.

Comment: Do you mean "1555" is legitimate for you? If not, then what I said in my previous comment holds - "1555" satisfies (passes) your conditions, which means you stated your conditions wrong. Alternatively, if "1555" is legitimate, then @Andriy M's answer is wrong.

Comment: @HelenCraigman: I agree that the description may not sound entirely clear. Perhaps that's why Alexei has added an example to help illustrate the requirements. My attempt at rephrasing would be this: the string should be a specific number; it may have an arbitrary number of leading zeros. (Of course, that primarily describes the problem that my answer solves, which you may well think to be different from the one in the question.)

Comment: Not sure why we talk about it while problem was more than year ago and successfully resolved by @AndriyM.

Comment: I guess @Helen just wanted to clarify an apparent gap in the rules as outlined in your question. I mean, they say what the field should begin with and what it should end with, and that seems to imply that something should (or *might*) go in-between. Perhaps, replacing "field should end..." with "the rest of the field should be..." would make it clearer that there should be nothing between the optional zeros and the number.

Comment: @AndriyM Ok, I agree. I'm not native English speaker so possibly I've made some mistakes. :( Sorry for this.

Comment: Oh, that's perfectly all right, just try to be understanding on your part too towards those who happen to be confused by your English. :) If you mean you agree that rewording the #2 like I suggested might render the entire rule set less confusing, please feel free to edit your question using my suggestion. Or, if you aren't sure how to put it correctly, I could do that myself. I feel that might indeed help in avoiding any such questions in the future.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps like this:

```
WHERE Field LIKE '%555' AND Field NOT LIKE '%[^0]%555'
```

Try this live [on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/1203).

Answer (score 1):

may be like this

```
SELECT * FROM table where CAST(field AS int) = CAST('your input' AS int)
```

Comment: +1 Could be useful for specific cases where only numbers are involved and the column cannot possibly contain non-numbers.

Comment: i think in his case need to filter leading zeros only

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, more specific to your situation (which could be expressed as *'The string should be an integer with an arbitrary number of leading zeros (including "none")'*) and inspired by [@timus2001's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10632098/297408):

```
WHERE
  CASE
    WHEN Field NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' AND LEN(Field) <= 38
    THEN CAST(CAST(Field AS decimal(38, 0)) AS varchar(38))
    ELSE Field
  END = '555'
```

The length test is needed if the value chances to be too long to be converted to the longest<sup>1</sup> possible numeric type. You could just use the `LEN(Field) = 3` condition instead of `LEN(Field) <= 38`, but then you would have to remember to change that part if the `'555'` requirement changed to something of a different length. As it is, you'd only need to replace the `'555'` string, if/when necessary (and remember that it should never be longer than 38 characters).

<sub><sup>1</sup> in terms of the number of decimal digits, or the *scale*.</sub>